# How to get babel to properly recognize es6 module names for import path

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I have the following director structure:

```js
js\
  foo-bar\
    abc.js
    index.js
```

Inside `abc.js` I have:

```js
export default class ABC { .. }
```

And inside `index.js` I have:

```js
import ABC from "foo-bar/abc"

export { ABC }
```

I'm using WebPack to build and I have this rule:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: "foo-bar",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, when I try to build I get the following error with `babel-loader`:

> ERROR in ./foo-bar/index.js (../node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./foo-bar/index.js)
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'foo-bar/abc' in '/Users/myname/projects/my-app/assets/js/foo-bar'
> @ ./foo-bar/index.js (../node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./foo-bar/index.js) 194:0-40 197:0-38

How can I get babel to recognize the correct module name for importing within the same project? I'd prefer to avoid relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

Paths in `import` statements are always relative to the current module directory (`__dirname`).

Try the following: `import ABC from "abc"`.

Additionally, since you are using [ES6 Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) I would recommend you to only use named imports/exports for many reasons. Specially to improve tree shaking on build.

So, it would be preferable to write:

```js
class ABC { .. };

export {ABC};
```

```js
import { ABC } from "abc";

export { ABC };
```

Assuming that you are re-exporting multiple modules from your `index.js` file.

**EDIT:**

Since you are using Webpack for bundling, you can use absolute paths if you want by preceding paths with a `/`. See the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/).

However `/` resolves to the root of your filesystem.

You can change your Webpack configuration as follows:

```js
const {resolve} = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: "foo-bar",
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve('./js') // OR WHATEVER PATH TO YOUR 'js' DIRECTORY.
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then try: `import ABC from "foo-bar/abc";` (without leading `/`)